# Kubernetes nginx ingress controller Redirect

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a website deployed in Kubernetes and ingress controller working.

I need to redirect my old subdomain to the new subdomain(old.example.com -> new.example.com).

I made some research and found that I have to use the annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target
```

my ingress file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rancher-ing
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - new.example.com
    secretName: new.example.com
  rules:
  - host: new.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rancher-logo-service
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: old.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rancher-logo-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: what is the question or issue you are having?

Comment: i need to add a redirect config from old url to the new one

Comment: yes, and you showed you have tried using some annotation, did it work? you got some errors? what happens after using it?

Comment: no, it didn't work. i didn't understand the docs clearly. how it will redirect if i didn't provide even the new url.
i tried another config but didn't work too.

Comment: please provide all of the steps you've taken to mitigate the issue

Comment: already updated the question with the latest config

Answer (score 1):

i created an ingress controller config for the new url.
and updated the old config into this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: rancher-ing-redirect
  namespace: test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/secure-backends: "true"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: https://new.example.com/
spec:
  rules:
  - host: old.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: rancher-logo-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: yea. do you have any suggestion? 
not sure if it's the correct answer but it works.